# Codeigniter - How to retrieve specific data on view after getting result array from model

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

So this is the function from model `Publicationdata` that sends the result array to controller based on the author id that controller provides it->

```
public function getSpPubData($tId)
{   
    $this->db->order_by("pub_year", "desc"); 
    $q = $this->db->get_where('rsc_faculty_publications', array('pub_author_id' => $tId));
    $error = $q->num_rows() > 0 ? FALSE : TRUE;

    if ($error === FALSE)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else{
        return $error;   
    }
}
```

now on controller i am saving the array as-

```
$data['pubData'] = $this->Publicationdata->getSpPubData("10006);
```

the `rsc_faulty_publications` table has a field `pub_year`.. now on view when I am accessing `$pubData` on view.. i want to print the publications yearwise. they will be printed in a loop when the current year publications will be at top.. so what I want is to fetch the yearwise publications from `$pubData` through loop.. the view is like this-

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($pubData);$i++){ ?>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; ?>" href="#year<?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; ?>" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: <?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; if($pubData[$i]->pub_year==date('Y')){echo " (".sizeof($pubData)." Publications until now)";}?></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year<?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php while($pubData[$i]->pub_year==$pubData[$i+1]->pub_year){
            ?>
            <div class="well well-info">
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_title; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_authors; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_publisher; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
            }?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>              
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#id1

Comment: i know how to retrieve.. i just need a method on how to group them by year.. n also for the loops i need the earliest year value for setting index

Comment: Have you tried adding `$this->db->group_by('pub_year');` on your `getSpPubData()`?

Comment: @sotoz i need the entire publication data against a person.. that is why i am pulling like that.. after pulling the entire data i need to group the publications according to years on view to print them in different bootstrap panels.. i dont see how group by is gonna help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $i=0;
$n=0;
$brands = array('info','warning','primary','success');
$len=sizeof($pubData);
while($i<$len){ ?>
  <?php if($i==0||$i-1!==-1 && $pubData[$i]->pub_year!==$pubData[$i-1]->pub_year){ ?>                  
  <div class="panel panel-<?php echo $brands[$n];?>">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#year<?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; ?>" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: <?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; if($pubData[$i]->pub_year==date('Y')){echo " (".sizeof($pubData)." Publications until now)";}?></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year<?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_year; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            }?>
                <div class="well well-<?php echo $brands[$n];?>">
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_title; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_authors; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $pubData[$i]->pub_publisher; ?></p>
            </div>
  <?php if($i==$len-1 || $i+1!==$len && $pubData[$i]->pub_year!==$pubData[$i+1]->pub_year){
      if($n==3){$n=0;}else{$n++;} ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div >              
  <?php } $i++;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First load the view file in controller and pass the data.

```
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

Use following code in the view file to retrieve the data.

```
foreach($pubData->brands as $brand): ?>
```

Comment: brands is not an attribute.. it's bootstrap brands which i am applying in a loop for different years

Comment: what are the column names of db table?

Comment: print_r($pubData); inside view file and tell me what do you got in return?

Answer (score 0):

after getting the value from model say
**$data['value']=$this->model1->getValue();** 
Now you can pass the value you obtained to view page like this 
**$this->load->view('viewpagename',$data);**
Now in the view page you can easily access it using the array name you passed .ie value. So in the view page do
 **foreach($value as $val){
print what you want here
}**

Comment: if i just wanted to print the obtained values in a loop.. i wouldn't trouble myself with so much explanation!